# Queue and Threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

### What i tried to do:

I tried to make program witch goal is add elements to the queue (in thread) and display data about queue (You can see data to display in main). Before that i wanted to delete one element form queue (every two seconds) and adding new element (every one second).

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::queue;
using std::cout;

void loadQueue(queue<int> &toLoad)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        toLoad.push(i); 
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    queue<int>toLoad;
    std::thread(loadQueue, std::ref(toLoad));

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "SIZE OF QUEUE : " << toLoad.size() << '\n' << '\n'; 

        cout <<"FRONT :" << toLoad.front() << '\n' << '\n';

        cout <<"BACK : " << toLoad.back() << '\n';
        toLoad.pop();
        Sleep(2000);
    }

}
```

### About error

When I start program i don't see enything. Program close right away. Visual Studio show me this messege:

[image: ERROR SHOWING BY VISUAL STUDIO CODE AFTER START PROGRAM]

Comment: `std::thread(loadQueue, std::ref(toLoad));` — this declares a local temporary variable of type `std::thread`. Since it is unnamed, temporary object, it gets destructed immediately after its creation. But see the [destructor of `std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread) — quote: _"If `*this` has an associated thread `(joinable() == true)`, `std::terminate()` is called. "_ You need to join the threads you create. (Or detach, but this is advanced usage.)

Comment: `Sleep(1000);` --> `#include <chrono> ... std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);`.  In other words, use the standard thread functions, not Windows specific ones.

Comment: Take the message's advice: Press Retry and debug the program. It's sickeningly effective.

Comment: There is clearly a data race in the code.
Several can access same data only if none try to modify it. Here both modify the `deque`, that results as an Undefined Behavior. All accesses to 'toLoad` must be done in a `mutex` protected area.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8400969

Answer (score 7):

`std::thread` cannot be destroyed while it's attached to an execution thread. In your case, however, you introduce a temporary in this line of code which gets destroyed the moment the expression finishes:

```cpp
std::thread(loadQueue, std::ref(toLoad));
```

You either need to detach the thread and let it be:

```cpp
std::thread{ loadQueue, std::ref(toLoad) }.detach();
```

or name the variable and keep it alive while your work is happening:

```cpp
std::thread thread{ loadQueue, std::ref(toLoad) };
```

Since you have infinite loop in the main thread, this thread will never be destroyed, but ideally you want to join it somewhere, e.g. at the end of the `main` function:

```cpp
while(true)
{
   ... 
}
thread.join();
```

Also be advised, that `std::queue` is not a thread-safe class, so you have to manually synchronise access to it, otherwise you have race condition in you code which is UB by the standard.